# Before she became queen, she had always said that she had not wanted to marry. - Indirect reported speech

Tags: reported-speech, past-vs-past-perfect

This is about indirect reported speech:

1. Before she became queen, she had always said that **she does not want** to marry.
   *Looks logical to me (since the time has already been introduced with past perfect), but is not correct.*
2. Before she became queen, she had always said that **she did not want** to marry.
   *Sounds good to me, but why? It surely is correct but shouldn't the 'did not want' be in the past perfect tense?*
3. Before she became queen, she had always said that **she had not wanted** to marry.
   *Sounds a bit odd to me, but why? Logically, in terms of the 'timeframe', it seems correct.*

### Other example (from a worksheet)

**Before John had lunch, he had run 10 km and had done the laundry.**

Is it correct that in this example past perfect is twice in the 2nd part of the sentence because it is to different events? Whereas in the sentence

**Before she became queen, she had always said that ***she did not want*** to marry.**

the part *she did not want to marry** is what she said, hence not a separate event?

Comment: (2) sounds the most natural to me. Are you sure that Swan says that (1) is correct? (3) makes sense if you change it to _Before she became queen, she said, she had not wanted to marry_ - implying that she changed her mind when she did become queen.

Comment: *According to Practical English Usage, Michael Swan (2017), this is correct.* I'd like to see some evidence of that. I'm sure you've misunderstood something, because example #1 above is *not* a well-formed utterance.

Comment: Example #3 is the reported speech version of her having *actually* said *"**I have not wanted to marry**"* - which is incredibly unlikely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - apologies, you are right. I confused something. I have corrected my post.

Comment: I don't see the point of this obsession with Perfect verb forms. ***All*** your examples pointlessly start with what she ***had*** always said. Simpler and better - *Before she became queen, **she always said** that **she didn't want** to marry*. It's almost always better to avoid Perfect verb forms if you don't *need* them.

Comment: [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) TL;DR: *As little as possible! :)*

Comment: No "rule of grammar" prevents you from asking about *Before she **had become** queen, she had always said...* But it's pointless